# RSA Decryption from Public Key Values

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm a little stuck trying to figure out how to decrypt some messages and could use some hints as to what I may be doing wrong.

I was given a series of integer values that make up my cipher text. Here are just a few of them:

6584 15650 16198 11003

I was given the following public key
b = 3001
n = 18209

So to encrypt a message M, you would use the formula:

```
C = M^3001 mod 18209
```

I understand to encrypt, I need to find a 'd' value that satisfies:

```
bd = 1 mod 18209
3001d = 1 mod 18209
```

Any hints on a technique or algorithm to help me find a suitable value for 'd'?

EDIT: I figured it out! I'll come back and post the answer in a week or two as I'm sure my professor wouldn't be too pleased if I posted it here on public domain while my peers continue to work on it.

Comment: "`bd = 1 mod 18209`": that's wrong. It should be `bd = 1 mod (p-1)(q-1)`, where `p` and `q` are the two primes whose product is `18209`. And to find `d`, you can use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures). (Or you can just find `d` by trial and error, as `18209` is so small.)

Comment: Is there a systematic way to do trial and error?

Comment: `for (d = 1 ; d < (p-1)*(q-1) ; d++)...`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Perhaps even [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask (if you plan on doing something with code).

Comment: You should solve the integer factorization problem (factor n); or solve the discrete log problem and use quadratic residues (to factor n).

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but please bear in mind that this kind of security practice is well known. This particular *answer* may not be though. Could you delete the question instead?